# How should I unit test a heuristic algorithm?

Tags: python, unit-testing, heuristics, traveling-salesman

So I've written an implementation of the ant colony optimization (ACO) meta-heuristic, and I'd like to write some unit tests. However, I'm not sure of the best way to test a method whose ability to return "correct" answers varies depending on various settings.

How does one unit test a heuristic algorithm?

Code lives at https://github.com/rhgrant10/pants by the way.

Comment: It's still a deterministic algorithm, right? Then given certain inputs, it should produce the same outputs. Test for certain results given predictable inputs.

Comment: I suppose I just can't shake the feeling that I'm testing default settings rather than the actual `solve` method.

Comment: What would be considered a correct answer? I'm not familiar with the algorithm.

Comment: Well, it's currently solving the traveling salesman problem. I've actually just written some test data that actually serves my purpose quite well. I ended up using evenly spaced points from a circle. I can simply calculate the perimeter. The algorithm works well enough that it finds it within the first 5 iterations with sensible (and default) settings, so I think that solves my problem for the most part.

Comment: @BrianKelly Despite that ACO (and other metaheuristics) can be implemented reproducible, it's not deterministic. Due to reproducibility, 2 runs of the same code give the same result. Due to being indeterministic, as the algorithm is improved, the result differs (and on average improves, but not necessarily for every dataset).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "take away massage" from your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test my TSP implementation with [this integration test class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/examples/tsp/app/TspPerformanceTest.java#L43), which does 2 tests:

- Asserts that it reaches a certain score within 600 seconds. I get that score within 10 seconds on my machine, so the long timeout is only for really slow jenkins slaves. If it doesn't reach that score in that time limit, it's probably never going to reach it. The point of this test is that no Exceptions are thrown (= smoke test) and that at least it improves the score in reasonable time. So it's better than no test :)
- Puts the solver in an assertionMode (FAST_ASSERT) and asserts that it reaches a certain, easier score within 600 seconds. In assertionMode, the Solver enables sanity checks in it's deepest loops (at a performance cost). This is to flush out bugs in incremental score calculation (= delta score calculation) etc.

On top of that, I have unit tests to test the specific components of my algorithm, to check if they behave as expected, for example [this unit test class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/localsearch/decider/acceptor/tabu/EntityTabuAcceptorTest.java).